# Remove character from string in Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I am trying to create an Android calculator which uses strings in Kotlin. I do not know how to delete a comma (or the negative) if it already contains one.

Here is my code which adds the comma correctly but doesn't delete it if the user clicks again:

```kotlin
if (!buClickValue.contains(".")) {
    buClickValue += "."
} else {
    buClickValue.replace(".", "")
}
```

Comment: You say you are trying to add/remove comma, yet your code implies you are adding/removing dot.

Comment: Sorry my fault. If you look at the code you can see that if there is no "." in the string, it should add one to the string, but if there already is one, he should remove it.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: My question is how do I remove the "."? // I added my git to the question, maybe that helps

Comment: Replace is not the good way to remove a char or sequence in a string: use filter in place of replace

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The `replace()` method is designed to return the value of the new `String` after replacing the characters. In your case, the value obtained after replacing the characters is never reassigned back to the original variable.

Specifically in your else clause, the line should be changed to -

```
buClickValue = buClickValue.replace(".", "")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem and explained it well!

Answer (score 18):

The more logical technic is not to replace but to filter

```
buClickValue = buClickValue.filterNot { it == "."[0] }

or

buClickValue = buClickValue.filterNot { it == '.' }
```

Or to extend

```
filtered = ".,;:"

buClickValue = buClickValue.filterNot { filtered.indexOf(it) > -1 }
```

Comment: The 1st exemple didn't compile anymore. I added ".get(0)"

Comment: This should be preferred over the accepted answer. Nice answer!

Comment: why not just ".filterNot { it == '.' }"

Comment: @Xan You will see a lint error that says "Operator == cannot be applied to Char and String".

Comment: @YUSMLE you spiked to @ Xan about my solution or???

Comment: @Luc-Olivier No, I was showing the issue after applying Xan's offer.

Comment: @YUSMLE got it! @ Xan is right. We can express a char with single quotes.