# Remove part of json string using Kotlin

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin

I fetch Json from api.

```
"fields": {
        "document": "some text: \n\n__textToRemove:__\ textToRemove \n\n__some text:__\ some text"
        }
```

How I can remove part of string? I want to cut "textToRemove"

Comment: Does this - ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344136/remove-character-from-string-in-kotlin/49344240)) - answer your quesiton?

Comment: In most cases it is the best to fully deserialize JSON with any library, modify the data then serialize back. It may sound like a quite a lot of work (for CPU, not for a developer) for such a simple task, it is definitely less efficient than modifying the string directly, but this is much more reliable and safer approach. If you don't need a very high efficiency, it is probably better.

Comment: And for serialization library I would suggest [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) - it is very efficient and it is de facto standard in Kotlin. If you prefer something more Java-ish, then [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is probably the most popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove back slash or something else with the help of this type of code.

```
  val dummyText  = "Lorem Ipsum is\\ simply\\ dummy\\text of the\\ printing and 
  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the\\ industry's";

  val fields = dummyText.replaceAll("\\", ""); or dummyText.replace("\\","")
```

and then convert into JsonObject. I hope it will be helpful to you.